# How to cross-compile Android emulator for Windows on Linux using existing AOSP source tree

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

I have AOSP sources checked out on a Linux system using the `repo` command as follows:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-9.0.0_r30
```

I've successfully cross-compiled the SDK for Windows but I am having trouble with compilation of the emulator. The prebuilt packages in `prebuilts/android-emulator/` are available only for linux and darwin platforms. I tried to add the needed repo by adding the following line to `.repo/default.xml`:

```
<project path="external/qemu-android" name="platform/external/qemu-android" groups="pdk" />
```

but `repo sync` responded with error:

> fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r30

which is understandable, because this tag indeed doesn't exist. In conclusion, **I'd like to have the newest awailable emulator (from master) built for Windows, but without the need for creation of the whole new AOSP source tree (I don't have that much space)**.

Comment: Why specifically do you actually need to rebuild the *emulation program* itself, vs. using whatever is distributed for everyday developers, to emulate your *fully custom system images* which should have little to no dependence on the OS hosting the emulator?  It may also be worth keeping in mind that Windows is the least fitting of the three platforms theoretically supported for Android work - typically app developers have a slight preference to sit in front of OSX while app build automation & CI, and AOSP work is mostly straightforwardly done on Linux.

Comment: I need the newest "car info" panel in emulator options.

Comment: Is there no *released* version of the tools with that?  If not, you may need to switch to a more fitting operating system to host development.  It will be of benefit in countless other ways as well.

Comment: I am aware. It's not entirely practical but is still interesting just because it can be done, but I don't know the Android build system even the slightest and would very much want to learn something more. If the packages weren't prepackaged for Linux, it'd still had to do it on my own and I'd like to know how

Comment: @Luke how were you able to cross compile for Windows? I am trying to compile for linux ARM64 on Mac. What changes did you make?

Comment: @SritejaSugoor It was a very long time ago. But I guess I used MinGW cross-compiler. I don't know anything about cross-compilation for Mac. About cross-compilation for WIndows: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Cross-Compiling_Under_Linux#Cross-compiling_under_Linux_for_MS_Windows